# Capacitance of parallel wires in checkerboard pattern

Tags: voltage, capacitor, capacitance, wire, equation

Below is a cross-sectional view of a 4x4 array of inter-meshed cylinders...

$$\begin{matrix}\Huge\circ && \Huge\bullet && \Huge\circ && \Huge\bullet \\\\ \Huge\bullet && \Huge\circ && \Huge\bullet && \Huge\circ \\\\
\Huge\circ && \Huge\bullet && \Huge\circ && \Huge\bullet \\\\
\Huge\bullet && \Huge\circ && \Huge\bullet && \Huge\circ \\\\
\end{matrix}$$

- \$\Huge\circ\$ & \$\Huge\bullet\$ are cylinders coming out of & into the screen, resp.
- Voltages \$v_o\$ & \$v_i\$ are applied to them, resp.
- Rows & columns are equidistant apart \$d\$ (measured centroid to centroid).
- All cylinders are same length \$L\$, dia. \$D\$, & overlap \$O\$.
- \$O\lt L\$.

How do I find the overall capacitance between them for a generalized nxn array?

Comment: Sounds like a school assignment. What have you got thus far?

Comment: It's not. I never had a question this difficult in undergrad lol I came up w/ it myself actually.

Comment: Teach yourself to do field mapping by sketching the *curvilinear squares*. You can estimate capacitance of odd shapes quite well. [Here is one example](https://pmcl.net.au/foee/Downloads/Lecture03B.pdf) but search for more.